# Program Overwriting Array with Null

Tags: java, arrays, null

For a project in school (intro to java), we have to make a program using arrays. I decided to make a login program that stores logins. It works perfectly, except when deleting items. This is my code

```
    public void delete() throws FileNotFoundException{
    int p;
    c.clear();
    c.print("Please enter a website to delete it's login info: ");
    String delete_name = c.readLine();
    Boolean found = false;

    // Search for the search key, and display the matching elements
    c.println("Searching for " + delete_name + "...");
    for (int i = 0; i < pass.length; i++)
        if (pass[i][0].equals(delete_name)) {
            c.println("Deleting login for " + pass[i][0]);


            String new_array[][] = new String[pass.length - 1][3];
            //remove an element
            for (int w = 0; i < new_array.length; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
                    p = w;
                    if (i >= p) {
                        new_array[w][j] = pass[w + 1][j];

                    } else {
                        new_array[w][j] = pass[w][j];


                    }
                }

            found = true;
            pass = new_array;
        }

    if (found == false) {
        c.println("No luck! " + delete_name + " wasn't found, please try again.");
        delete();
    }
        fileWriter();

}
```

When it writes to the file, anything after the part that should have been deleted gets changed to "null".

Sorry if the format is awful, I'm just starting with java :) Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You cannot set one array (pass) equal to another (new_array). See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882074/how-do-you-set-one-arrays-values-to-another-arrays-values-in-java

Comment: Btw I'm referring to the line "pass = new_array". Instead try "pass = new_array.clone();"

Comment: @Arman I do it in my code other places which works fine. It was actually in the course

`// Step 3: assign the new array to the old array
         grocery_list = new_array;`

Comment: That is not correct though, is this in a book? For example, having one array (arr1) and another (arr2), this "arr1 = arr2" will NOT copy arr2 into arr1. Instead it makes the two arrays refer to the same thing. Read the accepted answer in this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617016/how-do-i-copy-a-2-dimensional-array-in-java

Comment: @Arman I changed it to .clone() but it still overwrites anything following the deleted section with "null"

Also it is on the website in sample code where it shows that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When deleting a row of a 2D array in Java, you can use this shortcut (no `for-loops` needed)

```
List<String[]> tempArr = new ArrayList<String[]>(Arrays.asList(pass));
//Remove row at index of "delete_name":
for(int i = 0; i < pass.length; i++){
  if(pass[i][0].equals(delete_name)){
    tempArr.remove(i);
  }
}
String[][] new_array = tempArr.toArray(new String[][]{});
```

However, this solution only works if you are only deleting one object in the List. I would suggest looking into "`iterators`"  to make this solution better.

EDIT:

Here is an example with an `iterator`

```
    String[][] pass = new String[][]{{"Name","data1","data2"}};
    List<String[]> tempArr = new ArrayList<String[]>(Arrays.asList(pass));
    for (Iterator<String[]> iterator = tempArr.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        String id = iterator.next()[0];
        if (id.equals(delete_name)){
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the first one since I need to get this project done ASAP. I will definitely look into iterators though. Got it working with a few modifications. Thank you!